# How to cancel awaiting messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require("../config.json");
const q = require("../questions.json");
const db = require("quick.db")
const ms = require("parse-ms")

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  let user = message.author;
 let author = await db.fetch(`applytime_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
  let timeout = 3000;
  
  if (author !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - author) > 0) {
        let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - author));
  
    let timeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setTitle("__Application Error:__")
        .setDescription(`You alredy applied recently!\nTry again in ${time.minutes}m ${time.seconds}s `);
        message.channel.send(timeEmbed)
      } else {
  
    db.set(`applytime_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())
  
     const applyErrChannel = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("  **Access Denied** ")
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setFooter("You can't apply in this channel! Contact staff for applications channel")
        .setColor("RANDOM")

if(message.channel.id !== config.APPLY_CHANNEL) return message.channel.send(applyErrChannel);
    
function EachEmbed (contentIndex) {
        const dmEmb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("__Questions__")
                        .setDescription(contentIndex)
                        .setColor('RANDOM')
                        //.setFooter('Not replying will cancel the application')
                        
        return dmEmb;
    }
    
   const answers = [];
   const question = Object.values(q)

        const startedApp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setTitle("__Application Forwarded__")
         .setDescription('Application started in Dm By - ' + message.author.username)
        // .addField('Status','Applying...')
         //.setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        // .setThumbnail('https://miro.medium.com/max/1600/1*e_Loq49BI4WmN7o9ItTADg.gif')
         .setFooter('Application has been started in Direct Messages (DM)...')
         .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send(startedApp)
       
       const dmStartApp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("__ Application Started__")
        .setDescription(`Application Started - Type "${config.PREFIX}cancel" to cancel the application`)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
   let appChannel = await message.author.send(dmStartApp);


for(let index = 0; index < question.length; index++) {
  
  await message.author.send(EachEmbed(question[index]));
        let answer = await appChannel.channel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,  {max: 1});
        answers[index] = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join());
}

        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username + "'s Application", message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setFooter(`<@${message.author.id}>`)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        
        /* ATTACH TO EMBED */
        question.forEach((q,i)=>{
            Embed.addField(q,answers[i]+ `\n`)
        
        })
        
        const appLogs = client.channels.cache.get(config.LOG_CHANNEL);
         if (!appLogs) return console.error("[WARNING]: Log channel not set or invalid.");
        await appLogs.send(Embed)
    
        /*
       const finishedApp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("✅ **Application Forwarded**")
        .setDescription('to `application-logs` of server.')
        .addField('Status','Applied!')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/98/64/9a/98649add72e05e3cc1b8ae0e6f553c8e.gif')
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setFooter('You will be notified soon.')
        .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send(finishedApp)*/
       const appFinishDM = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("✅ __Application has been sent!__")
        .setDescription('Please be patient while your application is reviewed by staff')
        //.setThumbnail('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/98/64/9a/98649add72e05e3cc1b8ae0e6f553c8e.gif')
        .setFooter('Good Luck')
        .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.author.send(appFinishDM)

db.set(`applytime_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())
}
}
module.exports.help = {
  name: 'apply',
  aliases: []
}
```

How can I stop the application replying in DMs, for example if I type `+cancel` in DMs application question running its stop the asking questions.. How can I do that?

Like the application running when I type +apply it sent question in DMs I want like if we type `+cancel` in that time the asking questions also stop.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can simply add an `if` condition in your `for` loop that seems to be sending out the question and `await`ing the response. Exiting out of a `for` loop is simple, you can just use `break`.

Ex)

```
if (answer.content === "+cancel") { break; }
```

There's definitely more things that you'll have to account for obviously if the person wants to cancel, such as `answers`, where you're storing each of the answers, but that should be easy enough to implement, and it's not within the question scope.

Comment: ``` for (let index = 0; index < question.length; index++) {
 
 await message.author.send(EachEmbed(question[index]))
        let answer = await appChannel.channel.awaitMessages(answer => answer.author.id != client.user.id,  {max: 1})
          answers[index] = (answer.map(answers => answers.content).join())
 if (answer.content === "+cancel") { 
   break;
 }
} ```

Comment: can you `console.log(answer.content)` in the `for` loop as well? I want to check to make sure it's doing what I think it is.